# Magento - Get sales order number with (!$order = Mage::getModel

Tags: php, magento

We are using a module from MyParcel where the OrderId is being sent to the myparcel site. 
problem is that this is the internal order id from magento but not the sales order number.

does anybody know how to get the sales order number instead?

```
   private function _getOrder()
{
    if (!$orderId = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('order_id')) { throw new Exception("'order_id' not set");         }
    if (!$ret     = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId))   { throw new Exception("Order '$orderId' not found"); }
    return $ret;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have an $order then you have $order->getIncrementId()

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);
$salesOrderId = $order->getIncrementId();
```